# Using threadlocal in a singleton class in netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I am not sure if there exists any thread-safety issues
cause I use a singleton util class and there is a  member variable，
at first, I used threadlocal to try to avoid these issues. But the Nio thread pool of netty is too much small(the size is only 4, cause the cpu core is 2), so I am wondering that there exists some thread-safety issues when the concurrent level is high, for example：

1. nio-thread1 is handling requestA, and set the threadLocal value to a
2. before it finished handling it, requestE comes and nio-thread1 comes to handle requestE, and set the threadLocal value to e

So, in this situation, was requestA influenced? If yes, how can I avoid it ,if I want to keep this value as a member variable(not put it to a method)

Thanks for any suggestion!

Here is my code:

```
/**
 *
 * @param <T>
 *            source
 * @param <V>
 *            result
 * @param <K>
 *            key
 */
public interface BaseDecryption<S, R, K> {

        public static enum DecryType {
            AES128CBC, AES128XOR, XOR
        }

        public BaseDecryption<S, R, K> withDecryType(DecryType type);

        public DecryType getDecryType();

        public R decrypt(S source);

    }


public abstract class BytesDecryption implements
            BaseDecryption<byte[], byte[], byte[]> {

        private DecryType decrypTye;

        /**
         * Here is where I used the treadLocal
         * 
         */
        private ThreadLocal<byte[]> key = new ThreadLocal<byte[]>();

        protected DecryType getDecrypTye() {
            return decrypTye;
        }

        protected byte[] getKey() {
            return this.key.get();
        }

        public BaseDecryption<byte[], byte[], byte[]> withDecryKey(byte[] key) {
            this.key.set(key);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public BaseDecryption<byte[], byte[], byte[]> withDecryType(
                DecryType decryType) {
            this.decrypTye = decryType;
            return this;
        }

    }

@Component("LEAD_AES128CBC")
public class AES128CBC extends BytesDecryption {

    private AlgorithmParameters params;
    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    public static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AES128CBC.class);

    public AES128CBC() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidParameterSpecException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        this.withDecryType(DecryType.AES128CBC);
        initVi();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] source) {
        byte[] key = getKey();
        byte[] size16Key = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, size16Key, 0, 16);
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(size16Key, KEY_ALGORITHM);
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);
            if (source.length % 16 != 0) {
                byte[] encryptionBytes = new byte[source.length - source.length
                        % 16];
                System.arraycopy(source, 0, encryptionBytes, 0,
                        encryptionBytes.length);
                byte[] decryptionBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
                byte[] finalBytes = new byte[decryptionBytes.length
                        + source.length % 16];
                System.arraycopy(decryptionBytes, 0, finalBytes, 0, 0);
                // only multiple of 16 bytes will be decrypted, so copy the
                // remained
                System.arraycopy(source, encryptionBytes.length, finalBytes,
                        encryptionBytes.length, source.length % 16);
                return finalBytes;
            }
            return cipher.doFinal(source);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException
                | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DecryType getDecryType() {
        return DecryType.AES128CBC;
    }

    public void initVi() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidParameterSpecException {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
        params = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        params.init(new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

and I use spring

```
BeanUtil.getBean(encryType) // encryType may equal to LEAD_AES128CBC
```

to get the class.

Comment: Singletons are not designed for thread safety, So they should not have mutable states. I have seen serious problems in past because of such code, and we strongly discourage this practice.

Comment: Thanks, Anand. So I guess your suggestion is put the mutable states in a method ? But can threadlocal be helpful for thread safety or is it the suggestion way?

Comment: I think thread safety is not your problem. You have some data which gets mutated during IO. and unfortunately due to NIO you have got multiple threads sharing that data. So the question I have is WHY do you need a ThreadLocal on the thread that is handling NIO? I smell some design issue.

Comment: I use this because I use a singleton util class, and there exist a member variable in the class, so I wished to use threadlocal to avoid the thread safety issue, But then I think it can not work, can there absolutely exists  some design issue, but in this situation must I put this member variable to local variable?

Comment: Can you please post the code? I am not able to understand the exact situation.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! and I have post my code, I wish you could check it and forgive my poor English..( I use threadlocal in BytesDecryption  class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threadlocal in such scenario can be extremely hazardous if such code is known to be used by multiple tenants within same thread. Although we have an alternative which may make it little easier to manage.
Instead of `private ThreadLocal<byte[]> key = new ThreadLocal<byte[]>();` you can use

```
`private ThreadLocal<Map<Object, byte[]>> key = new ThreadLocal<Map<Object, byte[]>>();
```

and then whenever you want to get the threadLocal, you can access the same with the corresponding object. You may use `this` as your key, if you know that you are creating different instances for every request being made, otherwise you may use any other info like `Request` to map the key against request.

Of course you have an option to use static Map instead of threadlocal. Hope this helps.

Comment: It absolutely helps a lot to me, especially you said "extremely hazardous if such code is known to be used by multiple tenants within same thread", I have realized that, and what you suggest also makes sense, thanks again.